# Scala persistent key value store?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, key-value-store

Please advise on persistent key value store for Scala. Is it possible to use Scala Spark components to build such a store with good access times? (I am new to Spark and planing to use it). Thanks!

Comment: there is a lot of them, depending on your needs. mongodb or redis? also I have read recently about leveldb and mapdb, but haven't tried them myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark is a library used for data processing. The underlying datastore is normally Hadoop. So there is a conceptual difference between what Spark is and what a data store is.

You are looking for a persistant key-value store, I would suggest Redis because it is easy to setup, is relatively mature and has a Scala client.

However, you could also use any key-value store depending on your specific needs and what may already exist in your environment. Take a look at these Websites for some guidance:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL#Key-value_stores
- http://www.metabrew.com/article/anti-rdbms-a-list-of-distributed-key-value-stores